# How to correct error: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 6

Tags: xml, perl, utf-8

I am trying to convert an xml file into html file using perl code but getting this error that xml is not well formed and having an invalid token.
Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Parser;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::Parser->new();
$parser->setHandlers(   Start   => \&start,
                        End     => \&end,
                        Char    => \&char,
                        Proc    => \&proc,
                );
my $header = &getXHTMLHeader();
print $header;
$parser->parsefile('output.xml');

my $currentTag = "";

sub start() {
        my ($parser, $name, %attr) = @_;
        $currentTag = lc($name);
        if ($currentTag eq 'doc') {
                print "<head><title>". "Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4" . "</title></head>";
                print "<body><h2>" . "Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4" . "</h2>";
                print '<table summary="' . "Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4" . '"><tr><th>Tag Name</th><th>0</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th><th>10</th><th>11</th><th>12</th><th>13</th><th>14</th><th>15</th><th>16</th></tr>';
        }
        elsif ($currentTag eq 'GI-eSTB-MIB-NPH') {
                print "<tr>";
        }
        #elsif ($currentTag !~ /^(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16)$/)
        elsif ($currentTag ne '0' || $currentTag ne '1' || $currentTag ne '2' || $currentTag ne '3' || $currentTag ne '4' || $currentTag ne '5' || $currentTag ne '6' || $currentTag ne '7' || $currentTag ne '8' || $currentTag ne '9' || $currentTag ne '10' || $currentTag ne '11' || $currentTag ne '12' || $currentTag ne '13' || $currentTag ne '14' || $currentTag ne '15' || $currentTag ne '16' ) {
                print "<tr>";
        }
        else {
                print "<td>";
        }
}
sub end() {
        my ($parser, $name, %attr) = @_;
        $currentTag = lc($name);
        if ($currentTag eq 'doc') {
                print "</table></body></html>";
        }
        elsif ($currentTag eq 'GI-eSTB-MIB-NPH') {
                print "</tr>";
        }
        #elsif ($currentTag !~ /^(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16)$/)
        elsif ($currentTag ne '0' || $currentTag ne '1' || $currentTag ne '2' || $currentTag ne '3' || $currentTag ne '4' || $currentTag ne '5' || $currentTag ne '6' || $currentTag ne '7' || $currentTag ne '8' || $currentTag ne '9' || $currentTag ne '10' || $currentTag ne '11' || $currentTag ne '12' || $currentTag ne '13' || $currentTag ne '14' || $currentTag ne '15' || $currentTag ne '16' ) {
                print "</tr>";
        }
        else {
                print "</td>";
        }
}
sub char() {
        my ($parser, $data) = @_;
        print $data;
}
sub proc() {
        my ($parser, $target, $data) = @_;
        if (lc($target) eq 'perl') {
                $data = eval($data);
                print $data;
        }
}
sub getXHTMLHeader() {
        my $header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html
          PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
          <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">';
        return $header;
}
```

The contents of output.xml are(for example, actual file contains lot more details in similar format):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<doc>
    <GI-eSTB-MIB-NPH>
        <eSTBGeneralErrorCode>
            <0>INTEGER: 0</0>
        </eSTBGeneralErrorCode>
        <eSTBGeneralConnectedState>
            <0> INTEGER: true(1) </0>
        </eSTBGeneralConnectedState>
        <eSTBGeneralPlatformID>
            <0> INTEGER: 2076 </0>
        </eSTBGeneralPlatformID>
    </GI-eSTB-MIB-NPH>
</doc>
```

Actual error is:

```
not well-formed (invalid token) at line 6, column 13, byte 112 at /usr/lib64/perl5/XML/Parser.pm line 187
```

I have searched for solution and found some posts where same issue was mentioned but didn't find solution that could help me here. Following are the things I tried that I had found from various online forums:

1. Checked format of xml and compared at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_server.asp
2. Adding space <0> INTEGER: 0
3. removed - encoding="UTF-8"
4. changed "UTF-8" to "UTF-16" and "ISO-8859-1"
5. perl -ne 'print $_ if not m/^output_1.xml and used output_1.xml
6. perl -ne'print $_ if ! /^

   strings output.xml > output_1.xml and used output_1.xml

Please suggest if I can try something more. I am not sure if there's really something wrong in the xml or in my code somewhere.

Comment: Element name can't start with a digit. Therefore, `0` is invalid token after `<` where a tag could start.

Comment: Thanks a lot choroba. It saved me lot of hassle and I'll rethink about my whole approach now.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, could you summarise what you've done as an answer (and accept it) please?

Comment: I decided to have one xml element as "eSTBGeneralErrorCode.0; eSTBGeneralConnectedState.0; etc" instead of creating two separate elements. My apologies for delay in accepting the answer. Somehow, I am unable to see the option to accept the answer. I think it might be due to the post being little old or I didn't have required access for it (this was my first question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to follow choroba's advice and avoid having element names starting with digits.

I decided to have one xml element as `eSTBGeneralErrorCode.0; eSTBGeneralConnectedState.0; etc` instead of creating two separate elements. My apologies for delay in accepting the answer.

Finally figured out how to do this.